# Issues with ssh, X11 forwarding and gedit

Tags: ssh, x11, nfs, gedit

I'mm `ssh`-ing from an `Ubuntu-18.04` machine to `RedHat6` with `ssh -XYC username@remote.host` and I get the following warning:

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

I noticed that this is a common issue so I created an `ssh_config` file on `$HOME/.ssh` on the remote host (only the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` was there and since I'm not sudo I decided to create the file on `$HOME/.ssh`). The contents of the `$HOME/.ssh/ssh_config` file are

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
```

Note that `which xauth` returns `/usr/bin/xauth`

I think that this warning is related with another issue I have when running `gedit` which gives me the following when opening it

```
GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-uzs0GoBIFe: Connection refused
```

Also `gedit` doesn't run properly i.e. the settings I was using so far (line numbering, automatic indentation, matching brackets etc) are not used anymore so I'm suspecting that a configuration file is missing or has been changed.

The remote host is nfs mounted , so I think this is also related to that because of the message I get from gedit.

In addition using the `-vv` option when sshing I get the following messages regarding x11:

```
...
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0 2>/dev/null
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
...
debug2: X11 forwarding request accepted on channel 0
```

I also noticed that I'm able to connect to the remote server from another local host without any issues so I'd guess this issue has to do with my local machine.

Any idea on how to locate the issue and solve it?

Comment: Try running ssh with the "-vv" flag to print debugging output, then look for a debug-2 message starting "x11_get_proto:". This line will list the command which ssh ran (on the client) to get xauth data. ssh prints the "No xauth data" message if the command fails to output debugging data.

Comment: @Kenster: Thanks a lot for your comment. I updated my question.

Comment: The warning is probably because some xorg servers like xwayland no longer use cookies authentication and xauth. As to your problem with `gedit` -- try running **`export $(dbus-launch)`** before starting it. Notice that gnome doesn't believe in X11 forwarding or network transparent apps, and gedit will use the settings and configuration from the remote machine on which it runs, not those of the local machine on which it is displayed.

Comment: You can check the claim of my first sentence by running this on the local machine: `XAUTHORITY=/dev/null xclock` (or `xlogo`, etc). If it shows up, then your Xorg server is not really using any authentication, but just lets any program run by the logged in user in.

Comment: @user414777: Thanks for your comments. Regarding the first indeed a clock appears. SO how can I fix that? Concerning the second one, again indeed when `export $(dbus-launch)` I don't get the DBUS stuff but still `gedit` isn't working properly i.e. I can't change its settings. Any idea why?